# JbossAS renamed to WildFly. Shouldn't tags be renamed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

JBoss Application Server has a new name - ['WildFly'.](http://www.wildfly.org/faq/)

Shouldn't [the relevant tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jboss+or+jboss7.x+or+jboss5.x+or+jboss6.x+or+jboss-weld+or+jboss-arquillian+or+jboss-4.2.x+or+jboss-tools+or+jbossws+or+jboss-mdb+or+jboss-esb+or+jboss-portal+or+jboss-cache+or+jboss-4.0.x+or+jbossmq+or+jboss-messaging+or+jboss-web+or+jboss-eap-6+or+jboss-seam+or+jboss-eap-4.3.x) be renamed in Stack Overflow?

**EDIT** : I agree with what @Oded says. But, down the line, people might start calling it as 'JbossWildFly' because it is tagged so in StackOverflow(and this site is quite popular). Something like though WEB-INF doesn't contain **INF** ormation but only executables, but still its called WEB-INF.

Comment: You rename a tag and suddenly, everyone who knows the old name can't find those questions... A new tag with the old tag being its synonym is probably a better option.

Comment: I'd rather they changed the name back.

Comment: I have edited my question. Let me know if your comments still holds good.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say 100 people used the tag `JbossAS`, then you renamed it to `WildFly`. If other people didn't know about the new name change to `WildFly`, they wouldn't be able to find those other questions. - This is basically what Oded said above, +1 to that comment. I just tried to expand what he said in a little more detail.